# Regex that matches a pattern only if string does not begin with 'N'

Tags: regex, oracle

I need to put together a regex that matches a patter only if string does not begin with 'N'.

Here is my pattern so far `[A-E]+[-+]?`.
Now I want to make sure that it does not match something like:

```
N\A
NA
NB+
NB-
NCAB
```

This is for `REGEXP_SUBSTR` command in Oracle SQL DB

UPDATE

It looks like I should have been more specific, sorry

I want to extract from a string `[A-E]+[-+]?` but if the string also matches `^(N|n)` then I want my regex to return nothing.

See examples below:

```
String  Returns
N/A     
F1/AAA  AAA
NABC    
FABC    ABC
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the match is at the beginning of the string/line? If so, just start the regex with `^`

Comment: If there is no `N` at beginning then what should be there ? Few examples of valid match would be helpful.

Comment: no it is not, nor is it guaranteed to be at the end.

Comment: serial down-voter around....

Comment: @PedroLobito: No problem, I maintain my answer.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte you are really close but in the last example your regex does not work.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I'll do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, I broadened the scope of the problem a little, I realized that I can also play with other parameters of `REGEXP_SUBSTR` in this case that I can have returned only second substring.

`REGEXP_SUBSTR(field1, '^([^NA-D][^A-D]*)?([A-D]+[-+]?)',1,1,'i',2)`

I still have to give you guys the credit, lot of good ideas that led me to here.

Comment: It's great that you solved the problem, but what you've posted here doesn't solve the problem you presented us with.

Comment: I can see where are you coming from initially I thought that all I needed is the right regex

Comment: Btw, it should be `E` not `D` in your regex. Great work!

Answer (score 1):

To match a character between A and E not preceded by N, you can use:

```
 ([^N]|^)[A-E]+
```

If you want to avoid fields that contains `N[A-E]` use a negation in your query using the pattern `N[A-E]` *(in other words, use two predicates, this one to exclude NA and the first to find A)*

To be more clear:

```
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(coln, 'N[A-E]') AND REGEXP_LIKE(coln, '[A-E]')
```

Comment: That's still not quite what they want. They only care if `N` is the first character, not necessarily if it is before the match. `ANB` should still match `B`

Comment: @4castle:  not if you use two predicates (tests), the first to be sure there is no `N[A-E]` and the second to ensure there is at least a `[A-E]`.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that using two regexen (as you say) is the only way to go with this solution.

Comment: @4castle: abolutely not, you can build a (a bit complicated) pattern that ensures from start to end that the string contains only `[A-E]` not preceded by a N. The question is: is it efficient to do that?

Comment: No, that's not what they want though. A string like `BANANAAA` would need to match `AAA`

Answer (score 0):

Just throw a [^N]? in front.  That should do it.

OOPS...

That actually needs to include an " OR ^ "...

It should look like this:

([^N]|^)[A-E]+[-+]?

Sorry about that...It looks like the right answer already got posted anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that!